# check changes of my filter inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a html table. In my `<thead>` I have two line: one for column name and second for input (for filter).
So, in my template I have:

```
<table>
<head>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th> <input name="a"></th>
    <th> <input name="b"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
...
</table>
```

What I'm trying here is: I want send to server `a` and `b` input value each time a key is pressed, so I want to subscribe to changes of these inputs and I wonder what is the good way to achieve this ? I think here datadriven approach is not necessary?

**My Solution**
Maybe I can add `[(ngModel)]="filter.a"` and `[(ngModel)]="filter.b"` to my inputs but how can I listen to filter changes... I dont' want to subscribe to `filter.a` and again `filter.b` I only want to subscribe one time on `filter` object, something like : `filter.valueChanges.subscribe()`

For this solution I wonder  how can I tell to filter that it is an form type ? Need I put my `<table>` inside  `<form #myform="ngForm">`  ? Then in my template I will subscribe to myForm.valueChanges?

Please apologize if unclear, if not an exmaple is welcome! Thanks

Comment: Use an ng-change and make an ajax call in the function

Comment: thanks but this is not my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/78a9cyv4/

HTML

```
<input name="a" ng-model="a" ng-change="changeinInput()">
```

Controller :

```
$scope.changeinInput = function(){
    console.log("Call to Server ", $scope.a , " & ", $scope.b);
}
```

Explanation :

You can use an `ng-change` on the `input` field and use the `$http` functions to call the server will the updated input values.

Comment: Urfortunately, the above code is in angular 1.x. I see you are looking for angular2

Comment: please apologize i tagged angularjs I think i write only angular... yes my need is for angular2 and I want to use observable to listen changes and apply operator I need ... I don't want this old method used in angularjs. I want to apply maybe easy operator delay(300) so that's why I need here listen whole form but I wonder if my variable local #myForm when I use ViewChild in class I can subscribe to it

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the below simple code to acheive your task

in html

```
<table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th> <input name="a" [(ngModel)] = "filter.a" (keyup) = "sendData()" ></th>
        <th> <input name="b" [(ngModel)] = "filter.b" (keyup) = "sendData()"></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

in component

```
export class Component(){

     filter : any = {
                  a : '',
                  b : ''
               }

      sendData(){

        console.log(this.filter);
      }
}
```

here sendData() function will be called after every changes you made in a and b, you can send data to server in this function.

Comment: hey tell me if it works or not or if your requirement is different

Comment: this works but not my requirement I want to use powerfull of observable need to debounce 300 or 500ms and this with observable is very very simple I just want to send my #myForm an subscribe to it... noproblm thanks I will use FormBuilder I will forget my template driven approach, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solve it alone with this code: http://plnkr.co/edit/ir5Tn5Vgwuv1NUCkuQSh?p=preview

I heart it's not anti-pattern to use `[formGroup]="form"` inside all html tags (not only `<form>`)

condition: you need add ngForm because ngForm is automatically add when use

thanks